# How to combine RxJava Single & Completable Retrofit calls in Android Application

Tags: android, retrofit2, reactive-programming, rx-java2

My current Android Application employs `Retrofit` and `RxJava` to choreograph my network calls.

I have modelled my HTTP GET(s) as `Single<Response<String>>` and POST(s) as `Completable`.

The sequence of calls that I require are as follows:-

Sequentially call GET(1), GET(2), GET(3)

Parallel call POST(1), POST(2)

When both POST(1) & POST(2) have completed OK, call GET(4).

I have a partial solution. I have coded calls for the the First three GET(s)
followed by the POST calls

My code resembles this:-

```
Single.concat(getRequests())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                .doOnError(throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Manage Totals Failed", throwable))
                .doFinally(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        manageExecutions(combineExecutions());
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private static Iterable<Single<Response<String>>> getRequests() {
        final API_CALL_GET[] apiCalls = API_CALL_GET.values();
        final List<Single<Response<String>>> requests = new ArrayList<>(apiCalls.length);

        for (final API_CALL_GET apiCall : apiCalls) {
            requests.add(apiCall.request());
        }

        return requests;
    }

public enum API_CALL_GET {

    GET_ONE {
        @Override
        public Single<Response<String>> request() {
            return RETRO_SERVICE
                .getOne(authToken, new HashMap<>())
                .doAfterSuccess(this::persistDataOne)
                .doOnError(error -> ever(error));
        }
    }, GET_TWO {
        @Override
        public Single<Response<String>> request() {
            return RETRO_SERVICE
                .getTwo(authToken, new HashMap<>())
                .doAfterSuccess(this::persistDataTwo)
                .doOnError(error -> ever(error));
        }
    },
    GET_THREE {
        @Override
        public Single<Response<String>> request() {
            return RETRO_SERVICE
                .getThree(authToken, new HashMap<>())
                .doAfterSuccess(this::persistDataThree)
                .doOnError(error -> ever(error));
        }
    };

    public abstract Single<Response<String>> request();

}


    private static Action manageExecutions(final List<Completable> completables) {

        return new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
                Completable
                .concat(completables)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnError(throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "Manage Totals Failed", throwable))
                .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        accumulateAmounts();
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();
            }
        };
    }


    /**
     * @return
     */
    private static List<Completable> combineExecutions() {
        final API_CALL_POST[] apiCalls = API_CALL_POST.values();
        final List<Completable> requests = new ArrayList<>(apiCalls.length);

        for (final API_CALL_POST apiCall : apiCalls) {
            requests.addAll(apiCall.requests());
        }

        return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(requests));
    }

public enum API_CALL_POST {

    POST_ONE {
        @Override
        public List<Completable> requests() {
            return NetworkController.postRecommenderExecutions();
        }
    },
    POST_TWO {
        @Override
        public List<Completable> requests() {
            return NetworkController.postSavedSearcheExecutions();
        }
    };

    public abstract List<Completable> requests();

}


    public static List<Completable> postONE() {
        final List<Completable> completables = new ArrayList<>();

        final List<OneDO> oneDOS = fetchOnes();

        for (final OneDO oneDO : oneDOS) {
            completables.add(RETRO_SERVICE.runCompletableOnes(authToken, oneDO.getId())
                    .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(final Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            Log.e(TAG, "accept: ", throwable);
                        }
                    }));
        }

        return completables;
    }




    public static List<Completable> postTWO() {
        final List<Completable> completables = new ArrayList<>();

        final List<TwoDO> twoDOS = fetchTwos();

        for (final TwoDO twoDO : twoDOS) {
            completables.add(RETRO_SERVICE.runCompletableTwos(authToken, twoDO.getId())
                    .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(final Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            Log.e(TAG, "accept: ", throwable);
                        }
                    }));
        }

        return completables;
    }
```

What I am having difficulty with is correctly chaining my calls

e.g. I thought I would be able to develop a solution that resembled this pseudo code

Single.concat(GET_1... GET_N).onComplete(POST_1... POST_N).onComplete(GET_LAST)

however my current partial solution only calls the First group of GET(s) followed by the POST(s) and the GET and POST calls are not "chained"

I cannot see how to create a chain of calls that support my use case.

Is it possible to combine `Single` -> `Completable` -> `Single` in a chained call?

UPDATE

Based on Daniil answer I ended up with this solution:-

```
 Single.concat(getRequests())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnError(throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "accept[0000]: ", throwable))
                .ignoreElements()
                .andThen(Completable.merge(combineExecutions()))
                .doOnError(throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "accept: ", throwable))
                .doOnComplete(() -> Controller.accumulateTotals())
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: Why aren’t you able to use the operators mentioned in the answer below. If you want to chain observables and use the result of each one in the following observable, there are plenty of operators. For ex: map( result => use it in another function. Is this what you’re looking for?

Comment: I cannot try anything out until I return to work later in the month. Also I have no requirement to use results from any of the singles or completables, all I need to know is each one has completed Ok

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In kotlin it would look something like this:

```
fun generateGetRequests(): List<Single<Response<String>>> {
    return listOf(retrofit.firstGet(), retrofit.secondGet(), ... ,retrofit.lastGet())
}

fun generatePostRequests(): List<Completable> {
    return listOf(retrofit.firstPost(), ..., retrofit.lastPost())
}

fun doSomethingWithResponses(responses: Array<Any>) {
    // Do Something, like save to db
}

fun runRequests() {
    Single.zip(generateGetRequests(), { responses ->
        doSomethingWithResponses(responses)
    }).ignoreElements()
        .andThen(Completable.merge(generatePostRequests()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: This was close to what I required. I had to replace Single.zip() with Single.concat() to have all my GET(s) executed as desired. When I used zip() what ever GET request was last in the list never got executed. I also had to change .toCompletable() to .ignoreElements() as toCompletable is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Chaining up different types can happen either by converting them onto a shared reactive type (such as `Observable`) and concatenating, or using one of the [continuation approaches](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations) via `flatMapX` and `andThen`:

```java
 someSingle
 .flatMapCompletable(result1 -> {
     sideEffect(result1);
     return someCompletable;
 })
 .andThen(Single.defer(() -> {
     sideEffectAfterCompletable();
     return someOtherSingle;
 }))
 ...
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that would accept an arbitrary number of Single(s) and Completable(s); wouldn't relying on "andThen" mean I would have to match the number of singles and completables to the same number of occurrences of "andThen"?

Comment: Singles have values you'd probably do something about. Mixing them by themselves requires extra work, especially when they have different types. Adding Completables to the mix also incurs decisions about what to do with their side-effects if any.

Comment: In this case, all my singles return a Json payload which I "createAll" into my Realm local database. All my completables post a message and receive no response, so at a high level my multiple singles and completables are identical in their own way